# Group integers into pairs for the closest averages

Tags: algorithm, integer, average, pairing

I've looked around and found a few similar questions here, but none that address this specifically.

What I need to do is, given a set of positive integers (let's assume the set has an even size), group the values into pairs such that the average of each pair is as close to the others as possible - that is to say, that the set of the pairs' averages has the smallest possible range.

Example: If I have

```
[1, 3, 3, 5]
```

I would get two groups:

```
[1, 5] [3, 3]
```

So their averages are as close as possible- in this case, identical.

Is this as simple as pairing the highest value with the lowest, then second-highest with second-lowest, and so on, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Is the input array sorted ?

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array , and than take the first and last elements, the second  and penultimate elements and so on...

Comment: I know this would be the best way to do it if the data is normally distributed. Is there really no better way for a less-than-optimal distribution?

Comment: I think 99% of the time this will be the best solution in terms of RMSE.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you need. Is it better for your problem to have many pairs with average difference between their average and total average, or you would prefer to have as much possible pairs with average close to total average?

In first case, you can use your approach, in second, I will find pair which has closest to average, then next one etc...

E.g. for this input: `[1, 1, 1, 25, 26, 100]` pair `[25, 26]` has the closest average to the total average.

If you have even more specified requirements, you could use weights for different averages.

Comment: The average of the full set is not really relevant. I just want the range of the paired averages to be as small as possible, wherever that range happens to fall.